# How to display data to view exactly what it looks like in the database?

Tags: oracle, spring-mvc

I have system where in the data saved in the database have a format. The format in the database is not displayed in the view as it is in the database.

I tried to research but I can't seem to find an answer for this.

Before I save the data to the database I use this code:

```
byte[] ptext = initial.getBytes(ISO_8859_1); 
                String newContent = new String(ptext, UTF_8);
                message.setContent(newContent);
```

This will keep the `\n` until the data is saved.

This is what I get in the database:

[image]

This is what I get in the view:

[image]

I want the view to display the data exactly how it is displayed in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you wrap the data with `<pre>  the data </pre>` in the viewer?